# Trouble with union when joining three tables with slightly different data

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables that I'm attempting to join. All three have the following important columns:

```
StartTime | EndTime | ChannelCode | Data
```

We'll call the tables `live`, `legacy` and `backup`.

Tables legacy and backup have compressed data in 2 minute chunks. I have figured out how to get the correct data from these two tables via a union and using distinct.

Table live has uncompressed data in up-to 1 minute chunks.

Another process takes data from Live every 2 minutes, compresses it and places it in legacy. Then, at a later time (maybe up to 23 hours later) the data is copied as is to backup.

This isn't ideal, but I'm not able to change the design for a number of reasons.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is:

How can I retrieve all of the columns listed above from each table, but only have one entry for a given time period?

So far, I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT StartTime, EndTime, ChannelCode, Data
FROM (SELECT StartTime, EndTime, ChannelCode, Data
    FROM Legacy
    WHERE StartTime < @EndTime

    UNION ALL

    SELECT StartTime, EndTime, ChannelCode, Data
    FROM Backup
    WHERE StartTime < @EndTime
) AS Data
WHERE Data.EndTime > @StartTime
ORDER BY ChannelCode, StartTime
```

Sample data for the legacy and backup tables:

```
2015-03-01 04:04:39.740 | 2015-03-01 04:06:39.740 | 516 | <compressed binary data>
```

Sample data for the live table:

```
2015-03-01 04:03:39.740 | 2015-03-01 04:04:39.740 | 516 | <uncompressed binary data>
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to go from here since the timespans are different. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will have to shape (format the data) of either the live data (which is only one table to match the other two or shape the two other tables to match the live table then do a union as you have. Could you post sample row data from the three tables?

Comment: I've added the sample data to the original question. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it formatted it very well.